# Created Personal and Bussines Microsoft account with same email. Delete "Personal" one is it posible?

Tags: microsoft-office, onedrive

In the past I created a Personal account on Microsoft using my little company's email "name.lastname@mycomp.cl" (Chile). Recently, I bought Microsoft365 Business Standar and created a company account with same email.
The thing is that when I configure Windows 10, OneDrive connects automatically to the Personal account with 5GB limited space (and it does not show me my company files).
I need to delete the Personal one so Windows does not confuse the accounts and I only use 1 account for business purposes.
Is it possible to delete a personal account like this in Microsoft page?

Comment: If you can delete a Microsoft Account you would need to contact Microsoft to accomplish that.  How you delete a Microsoft Account would beyond the scope of this community.

Answer (score 0):

If you could use Group Policy on your computer, I suggest you try the policy of "[Prevent users from syncing personal OneDrive accounts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/use-group-policy#prevent-users-from-syncing-personal-onedrive-accounts)" first.

[image]

If you cannot log the same email address into OneDrive as a company account after setting this group policy, I suggest you [contact Microsoft online](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus/) for assistance.

But please note, closing a Microsoft account means it would deletes all the services associated with it.
For more detailed information,you may refer to "[How to close your Microsoft account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/how-to-close-your-microsoft-account-c1b2d13f-4de6-6e1b-4a31-d9d668849979)".